# How to make clang-format 11 put a space after variadic template decleration

Tags: c++, clang-format

I'm not sure what's going on and how to accurately describe it. Here's the source code

```cpp
template <typename ...Args>
void foo(Args &&...args)
{
    bar(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

My friend with clang-format 10 on Ubuntu generated this

```cpp
template <typename ... Args>
void foo(Args &&... args)
{
    bar(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

But my clang-format 11 on Arch with the same `.clang-format` file generated the following:

```cpp
template <typename ...Args>
void foo(Args &&...args)
//              ^^^^ Notice the missing space after ...
{
    bar(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

I didn't find suspicious changes in [clang-fotmat 11's changelog](https://releases.llvm.org/11.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#clang-format). What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I had the same issue, after some `git bisect`ing, I found the commit that introduced this change: https://reviews.llvm.org/D83564

> clang-format does not obey `PointerAlignment: Right` for ellipsis in declarator for pack

The reasoning behind this change is that you can either consider the annotation `&&...` part of the type (`PointerAlignment: Left`) or of the variable (`PointerAlignment: Right`) or if you want, put it in the middle (`PointerAlignment: Middle`). This change was meant to prevent an inconsistency between having a `&&` and `&&...` parameter (pack), which would be formatted like this

```cpp
template <typename Arg, typename ...Args>
void foo(Arg &&arg, Args &&... args)
{
    bar(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

with an older clang-format, but like this

```cpp
template <typename Arg, typename ...Args>
void foo(Arg &&arg, Args &&...args)
{
    bar(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

with a more recent one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for finding the commit that caused the problem. So there seems to have no way to get clang-format 11 to work like clang-format 10 (besides manually patching it)?

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the answer is no. We ran into the same issue in our codebase and will probably move to `PointerAlignment: Left` soon to avoid this inconsistency altogether. I guess a long-term solution would be adding another parameter to clang-format for the specific ellipsis-after-(*|&|&&) setting, but that can probably only make it into clang 13 if somebody is willing to do it.